# nextjs13 Internationalization unable to redirect / to default language

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, middleware, next.js13

I'm trying to redirect the url / to the url of my default language, the default language is in the i18n file.

However, I still get a 404 error on the / page, but if I put /en it works. middleware.js
My pages are in src/app/[lang]
I don't have a page at the root of app

middleware.js

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

import { i18n } from './i18n.js'

import { match as matchLocale } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from 'negotiator'

function getLocale(request) {
    console.log("getLocale");
    // Negotiator expects plain object so we need to transform headers
    const negotiatorHeaders = {}
    request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value))

    // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
    const locales = i18n.locales

    // Use negotiator and intl-localematcher to get best locale
    let languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages(
        locales
    )

    const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale)

    return locale
}
console.log("middleware not function");

export function middleware(request) {
    const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
    console.log("middleware");
    // Check if the pathname is the root path
    if (pathname === '/') {
        const locale = getLocale(request)

        // Redirect to the default locale
        return NextResponse.redirect(
            new URL(
                `/${locale}`,
                request.url
            )
        )
    }

    // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
    const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
        (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
    )

    // Redirect if there is no locale
    if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
        const locale = getLocale(request)

        // e.g. incoming request is /products
        // The new URL is now /en-US/products
        return NextResponse.redirect(
            new URL(
                `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/'}${pathname}`,
                request.url
            )
        )
    }
}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        /*
         * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
         * - api (API routes)
         * - _next/static (static files)
         * - _next/image (image optimization files)
         * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
         */
        '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
    ],
}
```

i18n.js

```
export const i18n = {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'nl'],
}
```

dictionaries.js

```
import 'server-only'

const dictionaries = {
    en: () => import('../../../dictionaries/en.json').then((module) => module.default),
    nl: () => import('../../../dictionaries/nl.json').then((module) => module.default),
}

export const getDictionary = async (locale) => dictionaries[locale]()
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        serverActions: true
    },

}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

[lang]/layout.jsx

```
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children, params }) {
  return (
    <html lang={params.lang}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

[lang]/page.jsx

```
"use server";

import { getDictionary } from "./dictionaries";

export default async function Page({ params: { lang } }) {
  const dict = await getDictionary(lang); // en

  return <button>{dict.products.cart}</button>; // Add to Cart
}
```